# Red Badge on UITab?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

I have noticed that some applications (BeejiveIM) that you can put the red badge on a UITab. What message must be passed to add a badge to a tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the badgeValue property of the TabBarItem.

```
UITabBarItem *itemToBadge = [[[myTabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:indexOfTabToBadge];
itemToBadge.badgeValue = aString;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`-[UITabBarItem badgeValue]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006928-CH3-SW16)